# Perl RegEx: returning one match of nested "or" subgroup

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

Say I have a text

`The quick brown fox jumps (over) the lazy dog`.
Then I want my RegEx-pattern to return, say, the word `hello` (not present in the text) or any word inside parentheses, in this case `over`.
So a pattern in the likes of:

`/((hello)|(\([^\)]+\)))/`

However I want it to return *one* match for this. This would only make sense if it's prioritized. That is:

- If `hello` is in this string then `$1` should be `hello`.
- If `hello` is not in the text, then return whatever is in the parenthesis if you can find it.

So in

```
The quick brown fox jumps (over) the lazy dog
```

the `$1` should contain the string `over`. And in

```
hello! The quick brown fox jumps (over) the lazy dog
```

the `$1` should contain the string `hello`.

https://regex101.com/r/H5bwKs/2

Is there any way to do this in one expression?

Comment: No, you can't do this. Capture groups are always numbered from left to right by counting `(` characters. There's no way to make different groups fill in the same number.

Comment: @Barmar There is `(?|...)` construct.

Comment: @revo That's a new one to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [branch reset](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) construct along with greedy dots. Order matters:

```
^(?|.*(hello)|.*(\([^)]+\)))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/FrbrVZ/1)

Comment: Another good link: https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html